# Application with common services starts automatically

Tags: android, android-service

I support the project with the next structure:

Library project, that contain common classes: Activity, Java classes and Service class.
Also exist 3 another project, that use this library.
In every project i use service, that start with next Intent :

Intent intent = new Intent(context, LibraryService.class).

Service is not shared, another application should not had access to them.

Problem is, that, if 2 or all 3 apps, that use this library, installed on device, when i start one instance, other application starts too. And I see in DDMS that all 3 application started.
I think, that problem in common service class. Is this true? How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest files. Maybe you are not properly filtering intents.

```
    <... android:name="YourApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.your.intent.to.filter" />       
        </intent-filter> 
    </..>
```